# django-cms remove plugin via API

Tags: django, django-cms

In my website I am making use of the django-cms (by then 2.4.3, now using 3.0.13) API to create pages in the backgroud when, for example, a new department is created.

```
        from cms.api import create_page, add_plugin

        instance.page = create_page(
            title=instance.name,
            language='en',
            published=True,
            template='template.html',
        )
        placeholder_header = instance.page.placeholders.get(slot='header_img')
        add_plugin(
            placeholder=placeholder_header,
            plugin_type='SomeRandomPlugin',
            language='en',
            department=instance,
        )
        publish_page(page=instance.page, user=User.objects.filter(is_superuser__exact=True).latest('pk'))
        # [...]
```

This works correctly when I want to create the page. But when I want to modify it, I first need to delete the existing plugin to create it again with the new values. But the official API does not seem to allow this. Is there a way to remove or modify an existing plugin?

Thank you in advance for all your feedback.

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer to this question, it will make it easier for others to find in future.

Comment: I tried but the system didn't allow me, as I had just created my account.

Comment: @roberto: Answering the question (even own question) should be done by adding an answer, not updating the question. Please read [faq]. You can also read more on answering own questions here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer myself.

Given the CMSPlugin instance, the method `delete_with_public()` allows to delete it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear from OP which exact version of Django-CMS this relates to, but it's possible that `delete()` *may* be the method which you need to run from the plugin instance, rather than `delete_with_public()`.  You need to be bear moderation settings in mind before calling one or the other methods.

Have a look at this comment and the follow up comments for references to the code: https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/562#issuecomment-488327

FWIW, `delete()` is what works for me on Django-CMS 3.0.9

Comment: I think that you're right, since I posted the answer I have mainly used delete()